# Not able to pull apk file using python

Tags: python, adb, popen

I am trying to pull apk file using below code but it is throwing error: 
`remote object '/system/priv-app/AmazonShopping/AmazonShopping.apk' does not exist`

```
pkg_id="com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping"
    output_path =Popen(["adb", "shell", "pm", "path", pkg_id], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    path, err=output_path.communicate()
    print(path)
    path=path.replace("package:", "")
    print(path)
    call(["adb", "pull", str(path)])
```

Please help me to get this done.

Comment: Is your devcie rooted? Not sure that's possible with unrooted device?

Comment: No, the device is not rooted. But it is pulling the package if I give the path directly like call(["adb", "pull", "/path/of/apk/"])

Comment: what is the actual path of apk which worked for you and output of `path` ?